# Is it possible to render React.JS component where the source of the component pulled from a rest api call?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am wondering if it is possible to render a react component if the source of the component is pulled from a rest api call.  For example if the component exists within a database.

Please do not simply answer with "I would not do this" or "it is not recommended".  I understand this is not the normal approach.

The use case is having a list of "widgets" that reside in the data store and are pulled in as needed.  As well as building up components on the fly. 
 Ideally this would happen at run-time on the client, but I would also be ok with switching to purely server-side react if that is the only way.

Note: This is different than code-splitting.  I have tried various way of invoking "import(...)" but since the component is coming from a rest api call I was not able to get this to work. If there is a way, please let me know.

I have seen an example that was similar located here: https://codepen.io/qborreda/pen/JZyEaj?editors=1010.  But it had a few restrictions. Namely any additional imports that the component itself would need.

```js
function loadRemoteComponent(url){
  return fetch(url)
  .then(res=>res.text())
  .then(source=>{
    var exports = {}
    function require(name){
      if(name == 'react') return React
      else throw `You can't use modules other than "react" in remote component.`
    }
    const transformedSource = Babel.transform(source, {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
    }).code
    eval(transformedSource)
    return exports.__esModule ? exports.default : exports
  })
}

loadRemoteComponent('https://codepen.io/tonytonyjan/pen/QEawag.js').then((Hello) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('hello'))
})
```

I had thought that I could store the transpiled version of the component and pull it into react.  But so far I have not been able to get this to work.  Generally the issue is that either the component does not render or React throws errors because it is expecting a component not raw text.

I also tried manually transpiling on the client similar to the "getting started" examples on the react web site by including the babel standalone processor and react scripts on the client (via script tags).

So I thought I would ask the community.  To recap, my question is:  Can I store a react component in some datastore, pull it into my react web site and render it?

- Can this be done purely on the client?
- Would using React Server Side Rendering make this easier?
- Or can this only be done through a build step prior to launching the site?

Any help is appreciated.  Either detailing the steps required, or a simple working example would be great.  And I actually do not mind following links to get my answer. (I know, shocking!)

Oh, in case you are wondering I have been using create-react-app to generate the app, but I have also tried creating the app manually setting up webpack/babel myself.

Thank you.